# How to check whether React updates dom or not?

Tags: reactjs

I wanted to check how to react does reconciliation so I updated the inner HTML of id with the same text. Ideally, it shouldn't update the dom but it is paint reflashing in chrome.

I have tried paint reflashing in chrome it is showing green rectangle over that same text

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
    return (
        <div >
            <p id="abc" key="help">abc is here</p>
            <button onClick={function () {
                // document.getElementById("may").innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = "abc is here";

            }} > Btn</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Expected result should be that paint reflashing shouldn't happen but it is happening.

Answer (score 3):

You are not using React here to update the text of your `p` tag but directly updating the DOM with JavaScript.

So React reconciliation algorithm doesn't even run here.

Answer (score 1):

In React, the output HTML is a result of the `state` and the `props` of your component.

When a change in `state` or `props` is detected, React runs the `render` method to check if it needs to update the DOM. So, in order to do this check, you need to store the parameters that determine your view in `state` or `props`.

Given your example, we could save the text you want to show in the `p` tag in the state of your component (using hooks):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App () {
    const [text, setText] = useState('abc is here');

    render() {
        return (
            <div >
                <p id="abc" key="help">{this.state.text}</p>
                <button onClick={() => setText('abc is here') }>Btn</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

If you are using a version of React that does not support hooks, you will need to transform your functional component into a class to use `state`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { text: 'abc is here' };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div >
                <p id="abc" key="help">{this.state.text}</p>
                <button onClick={() => this.setState({ text: 'abc is here' }) }>Btn</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```